# Angular loads white screen a few seconds before showing website

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7, cloudflare, angular-cli-v6

**Issue:**

Angular loads white screen a few seconds before showing app.
This only occurs 1 in 6 attempts of loading the website, mainly when I close the browser and reopen it and then enter my website.

**Expected Outcome:**

The website/app itself loads within 1.6 seconds most times. I basically want the white screen to stop showing for 6-8 seconds randomly. It's almost like the websites failing asleep, but I do get decent traffic to the website.

**Tech**: Angular version 7, AngularCLI, Cloudflare and Hosting with Firebase.

**Info**:

I get these 4 strange yellow warning messages in the console. I'm not sure if those are causing the trouble.

**Screen shot below shows what I see for 5 seconds plus:**

[image]

Comment: Probably just be the browser downloading the resources (script files). Normally the browser has these cached especially if the versions match (ie. file names match) but the browser could reload these from the server especially if you see it occuring when you close/open the browser again. The alternative is that the hosting site (ie. backend) is doing something before it serves up the first html page.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [preloading](https://brianflove.com/2016/07/21/preloading-with-critical-path-css/) some lightweight critical css that shows some kinda animation/splash screen while your browser is loading the other heavier resources from the server. This will reduce the amount of time the 'white screen' occupies, and gives the user the impression that the webpage is loading and something is going on.

Also, you may read more about [preload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content) here. 
Assuming you are using Angular, on your index.html, within the `<head>` tag:

```
<!-- preload css-->
    <link rel="preload" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" href="your-path/assets/preload.css">
```

And on your `<body>`, you render some kinda spinner that shows while the browser is fetching the other script files.

```
<div class="app-loading">
  <svg class="spinner" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
    <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your comments. I've done the preload solution with the css, but still takes 5 seconds with white screen on first time getting the app files.Then after its cached and then sites faster.

Comment: Ahh I see.. Hmm.. I have 2 more solutions for you. 1) Service workers/PWA 2) Compressing static files in Gzip or Brotli. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: I use cloud flare for those

Comment: Hmm.. Is your website very image-heavy? You can consider loading webp images instead of PNG/JPEG. Also, how about customising your webpack instead of using the default angular settings?

Comment: Most of my images are on cdn firebase storage. My homepage image above the fold is webp and 120kb in size

Comment: How should I customize my webpack?

Comment: I've managed to split the main and vendor file which gave me a little bit of speed

Comment: Yeah, by customising your webpack, I am referring to more efficient code splitting. I have viewed your website, and audited it using Google Lighthouse. The score doesnt seem too good.. Hmm, have you considered lazy loading images not in your viewport? I am afraid that is all I have to offer for now.. You should consider 
 using service workers too

Comment: The website loads really fast on second attempt because my cloudflare is caching it. Could their be something in my cloudflare causing this issue? my images are lazy loaded. I'm not sure how to use service workers or splitting my webpack?

Comment: I see.. I am not sure how I can help regarding cloudflare, as I am not an expert in it! As for implemting SWs in Angular, I would highly recommend you to follow this official guide! https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro